# Telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused (Postfix - Ubuntu 14.04 VPS)

Tags: postfix, vps, ubuntu-14.04, telnet

I have installed `postfix` following this [tutorial](http://www.krizna.com/ubuntu/setup-mail-server-ubuntu-14-04) but when I try to `telnet mail.mydomain.com 110` (995,993,143 or 25) it throws the following error: `Telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused`

I looked at [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/578418/telnet-unable-to-connect-to-remote-host) of ServerFault but it couldn't help!
Any clue how to fix this (or a link to another tutorial), I've been trying to install a servermail on my VPS for a week now, cannot get it to work!

Comment: Verify the name resolves to what you'd expect (ping mail.mydomain.com and check the IP), check that you can telnet out at all (try telnet to your ssh port), see if it fails immediately (probably not listening) or if it takes a while (probably firewall dropping the packets), see if it's listening on the correct port (lsof -i:110 etc)

Comment: @EEAA well I tried to change `chroot` in `master.cf` from `-` into `n` as it was suggested in the answer I looked up, I tried to changed `smtp inet n - - - - smtpd` with `0.0.0.0:smtp inet n - - - - smtpd`... but nothing seemed to work! Thanks

Comment: @SmilingDragon when I `ping` my mail subdomain it works fine, but when I try to `telnet MY_VPS_IP_ADDRESS 25` it throws the same error above, but when I `telnet localhost 25` it works fine! Any idea? Thanks

Comment: My recommendation to use ping is to obtain the IP address, the actual ping result isn't interesting.  You want to make sure that the name resolves to the same IP address that you think you are on.

Comment: If it works when you telnet to localhost but not to the NIC, it's probably a binding issue.  You can see which interfaces it's listening on by running `lsof -i -a -p <pid of postfix>` (or `netstat -an | grep 25` if you lack lsof).

Answer (score -1):

Run nmap on the IP address that the name mail.example.com resolves to. Nmap will list all open ports on the machine.

In the `/etc/postfix/master.conf` under the smptd you can add ports

Comment: `nmap MY_SERVER_IP` shows `25/tcp open smtp` and `110/tcp open pop3` (and others) well I tried to change `smtp inet n – n – – smtpd` in `/etc/postfix/master.conf` into `25 inet n – n – – smtpd` and `service postfix restart` but still cannot `telnet mail.example.com 25` Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: The line you add to the master.cf should read like:
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd

Answer (score -1):

Connection refused means the machine responded but something is blocking the communication. 
 It's nearly always the firewall.  Check your firewall settings to make sure telnet and SMTP traffic is allowed:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW

If you're not in a production environment where things need to be secure at all times you can try temporarily disabling your firewall (if enabled) to see if it works.  If it works with your firewall down then it's the firewall blocking it.

Postfix can be complicated to setup if you don't know what you're doing.  You'll also need to setup Dovecot if you want to check mail via IMAP or POP3.